# Return Value In Runnable

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I have a custom adapter that `buttons` and `TextView`, the `TextView` is changed on a `button` click within `listview` and it after sending and receiving feedback from `http` `Post` via `Json` response, I tried using `runnable` and `assynctask` but no success. In the runnable, I can not return a value from the method.

What I wanted is to send `http` request to the server and return `json` results, based on the returned results, the `TextView` will change.

What is the best approach to use to achieve this.

If any one can help point me to a resource that will help me to achieve this will be highly welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code..

```
    public String getStatus(final String id, final String user){
        final String[] resp = {"0/0/0"};

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Building Parameters
                final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                Log.d("Nay Params", "" + params);
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(NAY_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                // json success tag

                try {

                    Log.d("Nay Response", ""+ json);
                    success = json.getBoolean(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    yeaSt = json.getBoolean(TAG_E_STATUS);
                    naySt = json.getBoolean(TAG_A_STATUS);
                    yeaC = json.getInt(TAG_YEA);
                    nayC = json.getInt(TAG_NAY);
                    if (success){
                   resp[0] = yeaS + "/" + naySt + "/" + yeaC + "/" + nayC;

                           return resp[0];  
//Can not return return value within void method that is; Class void run()

                        }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //return resp[0];

            }

        }



        }).start();
//Can not acces json result outside the try catch block
        Log.d("sux", ""+success);

    //       Log.d("Rest1", resp[0]);

        return resp[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Callable interface in order to run a thread and get the thread's result.

Here's the Callable [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

And Jakob explains how to use it [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Hope that helped, if you need a concrete example I recently used this approach in my project, and I'll be happy to provide you with a sample.

**Edit:**
Here is a simple example of using callable, I changed a little bit my code so it is more clear:

```
public class Test {
ExecutorService executor;

public Test() {
    /* I used an executor that creates a new thread every time creating a server requests object
     * you might need to create a thread pool instead, depending on your application
     * */
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

private JSONObject doTheWork() {
    // init 
    Callable<JSONObject> callable;
    Future<JSONObject> future;
    JSONObject jsonResult = null;

    try {
        // create callable object with desired job
        callable = new Callable<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
                JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();

                // connect to the server

                // insert desired data into json object

                // and return the json object 
                return jsonResult; 
            }
        };

        future = executor.submit(callable);
        jsonResult = future.get();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        // Log exception at first so you could know if something went wrong and needs to be fixed
    } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
        // Log exception at first so you could know if something went wrong and needs to be fixed
    }

    return jsonResult;
}
```

}

Another approach would be creating a class that implements Callable. Whatever of these approaches you choose depends on your application, and maybe person's taste :).
Happy that I helped.

Comment: It really helped me a lot about Callable, I came across it, but was unable to digest it, but this really helped me. Please I will love for the sample code to be provided.

Comment: I edited the post with an example that might be helpful, good luck ;)

Comment: Gbam! Wished I can add another +1 for you.. ;)  I appreciate!